# Regex to retrieve at least 5 same numbers in a row

Tags: python, regex

Looking for the regexp for finding all longest digit sequences (starting with length = 5) of the same numbers.
E.g.:

```
Input: 'hgfd 0022222233333 4444 5556555 0000000'
Output: ['222222', '33333', '0000000']
```

UPDATE: Spaces should be ignored. E.g.:

```
Input: '002223333 3344 444 44'
Output: ['3333 33', '44 444 44']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the below regex to match all the longest digit sequences (starting with length = 5),

```
(\d)\1{4,}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sT0fL2/4)

```
>>> s = "hgfd 0022222233333 4444 5556555 0000000"
>>> [x.group() for x in re.finditer(r"(\d)\1{4,}", s)]
['222222', '33333', '0000000']
```

**Update:**

```
(\d)(?:\s*\1\s*\1\s*\1)(?:\s*\1)+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iQ2hK3/3)

Comment: Great! But I forgot about spaces. Digit sequence could not be interrupted by spaces.

Comment: Not working with `'0022233  33'`. It should return None as there are no 5 same digits in a row in the string.

Comment: @user3058525 see the update. And ask if you have any queries.

Answer (score 1):

`(\d)\1{5,}` return `['222222', '0000000']`

`(\d)\1{4,}` return `['222222', '33333', '0000000']`